# Attempting to compile class file through command line with javac returns "File not found"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compilation, javac

After downloading and setting up the jdk/javac path, I want to be able to manually compile a class file through the command prompt. However, this is what my cmd window looks like after I check for the version to see if the path is set, then try to compile a small class file from Intellij.

```
C:\Users\goel>java -version
java version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS, mixed mode)

C:\Users\goel>javac Main.java
error: file not found: Main.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options
```

The file is on the computer, and after the first failed try I also copied it to the desktop. Any help on how to fix this would be great.

Comment: You're in the wrong working directory.

Comment: How do I change the cmd window to work in the correct directory then?

Comment: Output should just be HelloWorld, it's just serving to make sure that this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run `javac` command from your project folder where `Main.java` file exists. From error you can see that there is no `Main.java` file in `C:\Users\goel` folder. Change the folder with command:

```
cd /d <path_to_folder_with_Main.java_file>
```

Comment: Ok, I tried this, typing in "cd /d <C:\Users\goel\IdeaProjects\src>", however it says that the syntax of the command is incorrect. I probably just misunderstood how you wanted me to type it @biruk1230 Edit: I'm an idiot forgot to remove the border characters thank you very much it worked.

Comment: try "cd /d C:\Users\goel\IdeaProjects\src"

Comment: Usually `< >` symbols is a standard notation for pointing that you need to change path inside `<` and `>` to the your path.

Comment: different question, how do I now run the class file? I have it in the same location as the source code file, but it does not offer the option to open it with java. Also, is it a problem that the compiled file is still labeled as .class? I thought once compiled it would have the .jar designation.

Comment: Now  you can just run `java Main` command. For details  see, for example, [this](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/windows/manual.php) and [this](https://www.baeldung.com/javac) links.

`javac` command only compiles Java source files into class files

Comment: For creating a `.jar` archives usually use **maven** or just **jar** tools.